# Getting a warning message with srand time null on Xcode

Tags: c++, time, null, static-cast, srand

Originally I just had a normal

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

And I was getting a warning message "Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'time_t' (aka 'long') to 'unsigned int'".

I looked it up and the only solution I found was to change it to

```
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));
```

It worked temporarily, the warning message was gone. And then half a week later I opened this window again and the warning message was back.

[image: Error with static_cast]

[image: Error without static_cast]

Comment: The PRNG facilities in C++ have been vastly improved from the C++11 standard. See e.g. [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) for more details.

Comment: And here's a presentation you should watch for the jokes if nothing else: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). It goes over the alternatives and explains why they are better.